# HTML Compilers that use live preview wth firefox INSTEAD of google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, frontend

Is there a compiler that opens a live preview version of my HTML and CSS in firefox? Programs like Brackets, cannot do this feature unless it is google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, this is a great tool: http://incident57.com/codekit/

If not, or want something else, this works: https://prepros.io

And if you want to be really hardcore try http://livereload.com or http://www.browsersync.io with a build tool of your choice